# Search Bar on top for all tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I am looking for the best way to implement a `UISearchBar` on the top of the screen for all the tabs in my `TabBarController`. I want the SearchBar to be consistent throughout all tabs (i.e. same placeholder text, same search text even after switching tabs).

Is there a way to do this besides passing data to the selected tab each time the user switches tabs? I was thinking of making a `singleton` `UISearchBar` and adding it as a subview each time the user changes tabs. I have my doubts about this approach though.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: add on navigationcontrolles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one **baseviewcontroller**. In that you can add your `UISearchBar`. After that you can inherit your each tab's ViewController from that **baseviewcontroller**. So, in each tab of your `UITabBarController` you will get that `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with that too until I tried something and it turned out it's very simple !

All you need to do is to add UISearchBar and a Container View in one UIViewController and then from that Container View set the segue to your UITabBarController and here you go ! One search bar across all the tabs and the solution will also help in separating the logic of the search functionality from the tabs functionality as you will not be forced to implement a search view across all your tabs.

[image]

Here I created a view controller with 1 UIView containing a search bar and an account icon and also containing a Container View (The blue part) which will hold out TabBarController

Answer (score -2):

You have to implement search bar in each view controller of tabbar.

Add UISearchbar in all the views.